# Weird device showing in network tab of Finder

Tags: macos, finder, network

This is what I see:

[image]

It is showing in the network section in Finder and I'm not sure what it means.

Sometimes I see it but sometimes I don't.

Should I be concerned?

My model is 2017 Macbook Air and I have Big Sur installed.

Answer (score 1):

It's a PC with sharing enabled.
It might be a worry if you're on your home network with no PCs in the house; but not if you're using some larger shared resource such as public wifi.
The 'worry' would be for the owner of the PC, having sharing on in a public location.

Comment: What is the script beneath the image?

Comment: @Tetsujin Not necessarily a PC.  Anything with sharing, but not identified by macOS.

Answer (score 0):

That icon is for a generic device with SMB sharing enabled. As well as other computers, a printer or network router may well have sharing enabled.

The worrying thing is the script beneath the image. That is a hint that there may be something untoward.

So you should be concerned enough to identify the device though it is probably not causing you a problem. Some suggestions as to how to identify the device:

1. If you connect to it (double click, etc.), you may be able to see what is being shared.
2. In Finder do a Get Info (Control-click and choose Get Info). You can then select and copy the name.  Open a new document in Text Edit, paste the name, and see if there is something readable (maybe change font).
3. It may only appear when connected to a specific network - e.g. home, work, or public wifi.
4. Turn off or disconnect network devices when it next appears. Turn them back on one by one until it reappears.